# dataframe Sort_values giving improper results

Tags: pandas, sorting, plotly

[image]

Hi I am trying to get the top 10 values.
I would like to get the top 10 attendance and punctuality by staff.
here's my code for sorting:
newData =data.sort_values("Attendance", ascending=False).head(10)
I'm not sure why am I getting 8.82 and 8.57. Please advise. I tried Nth largest but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because values in column `Attendance` are strings, so sorted in lexicographic order.

So need convert them to numeric:

```
data['Attendance'] = data['Attendance'].astype(float)
#if possible some non numeric values convert them to NaNs
#data['Attendance'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Attendance'], errors='coerce')
newData = data.sort_values("Attendance", ascending=False).head(10)
```